# Responsive Web Design/Media Queries

Tags: html, css

I need help to fix my navbar. I tried to add some media queries at the bottom of my CSS but I don't like the way my navbar behaves when I shrink the browser.

There is a space that shows above HOME button when I shrink my browser size to 768px. Same happens with 480px.

Also, I would like my navbar items to be centered at all times when shrinked to 768px or less, and when shrinked to 480px or less. As it is, it keeps my menu items centered only when it is exactly 768 or 480px.

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RHSab/

```
<header>
        <a href="#" id="#logo"><img class="topleftlogo" src="images/Mangosteen.png"/></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</header>
```

Also, why does the text from "About" section falls behind the following section??? Same is worth for other sections :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The space is actually your logo -

```
<a href="#" id="#logo"><img class="topleftlogo" src="images/Mangosteen.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You give the header a `min-width` of `900px`. Your content is centered into that 900px even when the window is smaller.

Also your `li` elments have a fixed width. The 'easy' fix would be to give them a width of `100%` when the screen size < 768px. Now they are fixed on 768 or 480px, causing the content to be centered in that fixed width.

But I also noticed that `display: inline-block` and `float: left` on your items. This is probably because of the 'normal' wide-screen situation where they need to be next to each other, but on smaller screens, you would get away with just giving them their default behaviour of block elements.

So actually, you have a *lot* of CSS going on, and as far as I can see, quite a lot of it is actually a work-around for other CSS you added yourself.

Comment: I just deleted it but it still looks like a trouble :(

Comment: Yeah. It seems the `li` items also have a fixed with (768). But I cannot find it.

Comment: It's at the bottom of CSS in media queries

Comment: Apparently my search failed. :) I found it now, but it's not easily fixed. The items behave like block elements, but actually they are floated to the left.

Comment: I think I found the quick solution, (see updated answer), but actually your CSS may need some cleaning up. Instead of making overrides for the smaller screens, you may choose to add CSS that is *only* for the wide screens, and make the elements behave as default on the smaller screens.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tried to make changes as you suggested but w/o success. I think I need a few hours break from this. Just to clear my mind.